# Python default value using logical operator

Tags: python, pep8

I looked through PEP8 but didn't really find an answer.  If I wanted to use a default value that's initially `None`, would it be better to test for `None` then set the default value? Or, take advantage of the fact that `None` evaluates to `False` when used with logical operators?

While example 1 is probably more common, is there anything egregiously wrong with example 2?  Are there any traps and pitfalls?

Example 1:

```py
def some_func(abc=None):
    if abc is None:
        abc = "my default"
    print(abc)
```

Example 2:

```py
def some_func(abc=None):
    print(abc or "my default")
```

Comment: Well, other things also evaluate to false - are all of those also intended to indicate "default"?

Comment: What if `abc` is `False`, `0` or something like that?

Comment: Ahh that's right! I guess that's the pitfall right there. Using `or` would only be useful if you can't have a value that evaluates to false. Thanks, it was so obvious.